# Modify jQuery calendar column

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have applied a jQuery calendar in my website, and it functions okay. However, the initial display format is Sun, Mon, Tue ... Sat, in which I would like to change to Mon, Tue, ... Sun.

Though I have modified all "Sunday", "Sun", "Su" in all locations within the site and the header of the calender works well, however, the arrangement of the date blocks are still as if Sunday is at the beginning...

Actually, what else I have to do inorder to correct it? Thanks a lot.

(Please note Apr 1 is sunday and should be located at the last column)

[image: Calendar]

Comment: see the documents of plugin your are using to display the calendar. or give us the link of calendar plugin

Comment: * jQuery UI 1.8.17
 *
 * Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI

Comment: Post the code you're using to make this calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see in the documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) that you can set option first day

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ firstDay: 1 });
```

Sunday is 0, Monday is 1

Cheers

Comment: Hi, does it mean I have to change all firstDay: 0 to firstDay: 1 within the whole site, and no need to make other changes? Thanks!

Comment: @Ham yes instead of $( ".selector" ).datepicker(); for initialization use $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ firstDay: 1 });

Answer (score 0):

```
put this code in your jquery datepicker function where you define defaults
dayNamesMin:[ 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']
 if not then try this one 
 dayNamesShort:[ 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat','Sun']
```